# How to know file position in Node.js? - return value of lseek

Tags: javascript, node.js

Reading [fs.read](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) and [fs.write](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_string_position_encoding_callback), it seems that in Node.js no interface to the C function [lseek](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) is directly exposed; the current file descriptor position can be changed right before any `fs.read` or `fs.write` by the argument `position`.

I strongly suspect that, at low level, the argument `position` is handled with an `lseek` call before the read or write operation, but what about the return value of `lseek`?

To be more specific, to get the current file descriptor position in C, I can write:

```
int position = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

Is there a way in Node.js to get the same information?

Comment: "current file descriptor position can be changed right before any `fs.read` or `fs.write` by the argument `position`": *Except* "On Linux, positional writes don't work when the file is opened in append mode. The kernel ignores the position argument and always appends the data to the end of the file."

Comment: BTW, how do want to utilize the offset returned by `lseek`? What is the use-case?

Comment: Nothing specific @Azeem ; I wrote [rotating-file-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream), a simple Node.js package for log rotation and thinking to new features I thought this could be an useful info. And thank you for the clarification in your first comment

Comment: Maybe this can be useful to you [how-to-get-current-offset-of-stream-or-file-descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237517/how-to-get-current-offset-of-stream-or-file-descriptor)

Comment: @Azeem One use-case would be when reading (huge) files and one want to navigate back and forth. For example one can have a file with headers / sections that give relative offsets. I.e. read header at offset 0, it say `you find section x of size 512 at offset 12345`, Section x say you'll find block y at at relative offset +6332, -334 etc ... One can of course keep track manually, but makes for one more place to introduce a bug + makes abstraction harder in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's no "native" way for this. Probably because of

> **It is unsafe** to use fs.write***() multiple times on the same file **without waiting** for the callback.

It would be even more so with something like `getCurrentPosition` for a **buffered** IO. What it should return after `write***` or `read***` but before the callback is called?

But you can try and keep track of the current position yourself with the help of [`bytesRead`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) and [`bytesWritten`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback). And in case of streams there is `chunk.length`, but don't forget about encodings in case of strings.

---

As a side note... you've wrote:

> thinking to new features I thought this could be an useful info

If no one requested it, and you yourself is not sure what it can be used for, then I think it's a good idea to exercise YAGNI principle.

Comment: Atomic seek+write would be nice.  The Node API should either guarantee it by removing the "it's unsafe to not wait" warning, or they should stop pretending it's atomic and give us a "getCurrentPosition" method.  If the Node API did guarantee atomicity then the async return value should include the actual position used in write and read operations that did not specify the position explicitly.  That way, programmers who want to write intra-file pointers in huge files can do so without having to track the file position themselves.

Answer (score 1):

> I strongly suspect that, at low level, the argument position is handled with an lseek call before the read or write operation, but what about the return value of lseek?

It is not used under the hood as said by [Ben Noordhuis](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/libuv/iMmRuNorJcw) (libuv maintainer) :

> lseek() is unpredictable with
> concurrent readers or writers.  The libuv way is to use positional
> reads and writes (the offset argument to uv_fs_read() and
> uv_fs_write().)

[This issue on node.js GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23433) talk about how they manage the position argument to read and write data into the file.

> Is there a way in Node.js to get the same information?

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357060/3309466) explain well how to do that: you need to track the read and written bytes.

Answer (score -1):

In Node.js you can use `fs.read()` and `fs.write()` for same.

Node can tell you where in the file system it is working by using the `_filename` and `_dirname` variables. The filename variable provides the absolute path to the file that is currently executing; dirname provides the absolute path to the working directory where the file being executed is located. Neither variable has to be imported from any modules because each is provided standard.

A simple example using both variables appears below:

console.log("This file is " `+__filename`);
console.log("It's located in " `+__dirname`);